# Split MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, multiple-databases

I have a question about split databases. This is the query in question:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM monies.link_monies_new lcn '
         . 'INNER JOIN products.link l ON lcn.link_id = l.link_id '
         . 'INNER JOIN products.products_format af ON l.product_format_id = af.product_format_id '
         . 'INNER JOIN products.products_categories ac ON af.product_category_id = ac.product_category_id '
         . 'WHERE lcn.click_time BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1311721200) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1311807600) '
         . 'AND ac.product_category_id = 1
```

The problem is that now the databases monies and products will be in different servers. What is the solution? Do I need two queries? I am a bit lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html

If I've understood your question properly, you want to have a query joining tables between 2 databases, and the databases will be located on separate servers.

Assuming you run the query on the "monies" server, you would create federated tables on the monies server, pointing at the "products" server. That way, your queries continue to work, and MySQL magically manages the fact they're on physically separate servers.

Performance tuning could be problematic, but it's the simplest way to keep your queries working as they are now.

For instance, you could create a local database on the "monies" server called "products"; within products, you would create a "link" table:

```
CREATE TABLE link (
    link_id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ....<<other columns from the link table>>
    PRIMARY KEY  (link_id)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED

CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@products_server:9306/products/link';
```

You could then run the query above without changing anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the tables are already created, it's a big system of hundreds of tables and I don't have that option.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how would you do this? Do I have to change the current tables to federated? I'm a bit of a noob on MySQL even though this task is complex. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to migrate the data anyway when you're moving to the new server so you can implement the federated tables beforehand.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution like this for ages!